# Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen nachschlagen und nachlesen?

Tags: difference, vocabulary

Ich würde gerne wissen, ob es einen Unterschied zwischen *nachschlagen* und *nachlesen* gibt. Beide übersetzen auf Englisch zu : "to look up"

Oder sind sie Synonyme? Oder können wir sie in Sätzen wechseln?

z.B.

> Schlag mal dieses Wort bei Wikipedia nach

So können wir hier auch sagen

> Lies mal dieses Wort bei Wikipedia nach

Comment: Interestingly: *Kann ich noch einen Nachschlag bekommen?* means something completele different: people use this phase for example in a canteen to ask for an add-on helping of the food they bought and finished.

Comment: Danke für die Auskunft @ChristianGeiselmann. Das ist interessant.

Comment: In a musical context, Nachschlag denotes either backbeat or a trill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Für mich besteht der Unterschied eher darin, dass man bei *Nachschlagen* ein einzelnes, eher begrenztes, konkretes Stückchen Information erlangen will:

- Die genaue Bedeutung eines (Fremd-)Wortes im Lexikon
- Den genauen Längen- und Breitengrad eines Ortes in einem geografischen Werk
- Die exakte Schreibweise eines Wortes im Duden (o.ä.)
- Den Wortlaut eines Zitats oder einer Textzeile eines Liedes

*Nachlesen* impliziert für mich das Lesen einer längeren Textpassage:

- Die Erklärung eines Sachverhalts in einem Fachbuch, einem populärwissenschaftlichen Artikel oder Wikipedia
- In einem Roman einen Dialog oder die Beschreibung, was die Person beim Betreten des Raumes alles sieht oder empfindet
- Den Werdegang einer realen Person in einem Personenlexikon oder einem biografischen Wikipedia-Artikel

Answer (score 5):

- **nachschlagen**
  Dieses Verb hat seinen Ursprung im *aufschlagen* (öffnen) eine Buches und im *umschlagen* (umblättern) der Buchseiten. Es bezieht sich also auf das rasche Umblättern der Papierseiten wenn man einen Eintrag in einem Lexikon oder einem ähnlichen physischen Buch sucht.
- **nachlesen**
  Hier ist gemeint, dass man etwas spezifisches liest.

Der Unterschied ist also das Medium, aus dem man eine Information bezieht. Nachschlagen setzt voraus, dass es Seiten gibt, die man umblättern kann. Nachlesen kann man in jedem Medium.

Allerdings gibt es in allen Sprachen unzählige Beispiele für Begriffe, die im übertragenen Sinn verwendet werden. Da wird schon mal ganz ohne Säge am Sessel des Chefs gesägt, oder ein hinterhältiger Kollege pinkelt jemandem ans Bein, ohne dass dabei irgendwelche Flüssigkeiten fließen. Wenn die Sonne vom Himmel lacht wird niemand ihr Gelächter hören. Daher darf man ruhig auch mal etwas in einem elektronischen Medium *nachschlagen.*

Comment: "Dieses Verb hat ..." Ne, hat es nicht, wenn ich das vielleicht mal nachschlagen darf. Der *Nachschlag* beim Essen, also die zweite Portion, hat doch auch nix damit zu tun, dass der Kellner mit Keller feste auf die Schüssel kloppt.

Comment: @vectory: Ich sehe momentan aber auch kein anderes Wort, das "schlagen" beinhaltet und etwas mit Besteck zu tun hätte. Der Begriff "aufschlagen" ist dahingegen in Bezug auf blätterbare Schriftstücke sehr verbreitet und eine Verwandtschaft zu "nachschlagen" scheint naheliegend, auch wenn ein Beleg der Aussage durch eine Quelle sicher vorzuziehen wäre.

Answer (score 3):

'Nachschlagen' ist für mich sehr stark mit Lexika, Wörterbüchern und anderen Informationssammlungen in Printversion assoziiert; 'nachlesen' heißt für mich 'noch einmal und ggf. genauer lesen', was man in der Zwischenzeit vergessen oder beim ersten Lesen nur flüchtig aufgenommen hat.

Answer (score 1):

**Nachlesen** ist der Oberbegriff dafür, durch Lesen eines Textes etwas zu prüfen oder zu erfahren.

**Nachschlagen** oder **nachblättern** ist spezieller, denn es setzt voraus, dass die betreffende Textstelle in einem echten Buch oder Heft steht und man sie durch Umschlagen der Blätter suchen muss.

Auch wenn ich verstehe, was mit *bei Wikipedia nachschlagen/ nachblättern* gemeint ist, klingt das in meinen Ohren sehr merkwürdig.

Comment: Wieso sollte *nachschlagen* mit *eine Seite umschlagen* gleichgesetzt werden, haben Sie einen Beleg dafür? Z.b. hat *jmdm. Nachstellen* doch auch nichts (mehr?) mit *stehen* zu tun--ganz im Gegenteil!

Answer (score 1):

Ich verbinde mit nachlesen, einen bestimmten Text erstmalig oder wiederholt zu lesen. Zweck ist die Überprüfung einer Information/ Aussage.
Nachschlagen ist eher damit verbunden, eine Information zu finden, zu erarbeiten.